# Firebase security rules ensure children conditional

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the Firebase [Bolt Compiler](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) to build my security rules and I've come across the following scenario:

- I have some nested data that I want to post to Firebase in the following form:

  ```
  data: {
    a: //Number, must always be present
    b: //Number, conditionally present (condition B)
    c: //Number, conditionally present (condition C)
  }
  ```
- Conditions B and C are based on a piece of data, elsewhere is Firebase, and if met, I want the values included, but if not met, I want to values to be `null`

  ```
  root.condition >= 5  //condition B
  root.condition >= 10 //condition C
  ```

The following is my attempt, using Bolt, to construct these rules:

```
type ConditionB extends Number {
  validate() = root.condition >= 5 ? this != null : this == null;
} 

type ConditionC extends Number {
  validate() = root.condition >= 10 ? this != null : this == null;
}

type Data {
  a: Number,
  b: ConditionB,
  c: ContitionC
}

path /data is Data {
  read()  = true,
  write() = true
}
```

Here is the following rules.json:

```
"rules": {
  "data": {
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['a', 'b', 'c']),
    ...
  }
}
```

It can be seen that the `.validate` rule enforces all children to be present in `data`. So, how can I ensure that, based on my conditions, the `.validate` rules for both `data` and each of its children are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your type can be Null, you must extend Number | Null like so:

```
type ConditionB extends Number | Null {
  validate() = root.condition >= 5 ? this != null : this == null;
}

type ConditionC extends Number | Null {
  validate() = root.condition >= 10 ? this != null : this == null;
}

type Data {
  a: Number,
  b: ConditionB,
  c: ConditionC
}

path /data is Data {
  read() = true;
  write() = true;
}
```

Which results in the following JSON rules file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "data": {
      ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['a'])",
      "a": {
        ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
      },
      "b": {
        ".validate": "(newData.isNumber() || newData.val() == null) && (newData.parent().parent().child('condition').val() >= 5 ? newData.val() != null : newData.val() == null)"
      },
      "c": {
        ".validate": "(newData.isNumber() || newData.val() == null) && (newData.parent().parent().child('condition').val() >= 10 ? newData.val() != null : newData.val() == null)"
      },
      "$other": {
        ".validate": "false"
      },
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tip: If you don't like seeing newData.parent()..., use prior(root) in your validation expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and extra tip! I didn't realize that you could OR types in `extend`, that would be great to see added to the docs (or maybe it is and I skipped over it :))